# Visualizar PDF dentro de mi app AndroidStudio

Tags: android-studio, firebase, webview, firestore

[image: Publicaciones][image: Detalle de la publicacion]

La imagen "Publicaciones" muestra cards de los post que realizan los usuarios.
La otra imagen muestra el contenido que tiene cada "card".
Tengo una coleccion "Posts" en Firestore que contiene: idUser, titulo del PDF, descripcion y la Url del PDF(previamente almacenado desde la misma app)

Hice un llamado a la base de datos (FirebaseFirestore) para obtener el título y la descripción del PDF.
En la parte final le implementé un botón para que cualquier usuario que vea el post puedar ver el PDF lo cual no logro hacer que funcione.

//Tengo un PostProvider en el cual se creó el método "getPostById", de ese provider me estoy trayendo el título y la descripción del PDF

```
private void getPost(){
    mPostProvider.getPostById(mExtraPostId).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
            if (documentSnapshot.exists()){
                if (documentSnapshot.contains("title")){
                    String title = documentSnapshot.getString("title");
                    mTitlePdf.setText(title);
                }

                if (documentSnapshot.contains("description")){
                    String description = documentSnapshot.getString("description");
                    mDescrPdf.setText(description);
                }

            }

        }
    });

}
```

//Cuando se hace clic en el botón llama a esta activity el la cual quiero que se muestre el PDF en un WebView pero no lo muestra, se queda cargando y vuelve a la vista de publicaciones. Ya he visto varios videos y lo hacen de esta manera. Al compilar no muestra ningún error

```
PostProvider mPostProvider;
String mExtraPostId;
WebView mWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_pdf);

   mPostProvider = new PostProvider();
   mExtraPostId = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
   VistaPdf();

    mWebView = findViewById(R.id.WebViewPdf);

}

private void VistaPdf() {

    mPostProvider.getPostById(mExtraPostId).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
            if (documentSnapshot.exists()){
                if (documentSnapshot.contains("imPDFurl")){
                    String urlPdf = documentSnapshot.getString("imPDFurl");
                    if (urlPdf != null && !urlPdf.isEmpty()){

                        String url = "";
                        try {
                            url = URLEncoder.encode(urlPdf,"UTF-8");
                            mWebView.loadUrl( "http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url="  + url);
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(ViewPdfActivity.this, "no se pudo abrir el PDF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Revisa el LogCat por favor

Answer (score 0):

Te comparto la configuracion del webView, como lo hago en kotlin para android movil:

```
my_WebView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true  //habilitar javascript
        my_WebView.settings.setSupportZoom(true)  //habilitar zoom en la vista web
        my_WebView.settings.builtInZoomControls = true //permitir pellizcar para hacer zoom
        my_WebView.settings.displayZoomControls = true //deshabilitar controles predeterminados en la pagina
        my_WebView.settings.useWideViewPort = true  //habilitar diseño receptivo
        my_WebView.settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true  //reducir si el ancho del contenido es mayor que el ancho de la ventana
        my_WebView.settings.allowFileAccess = true
        my_WebView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
val url = "https://tu-ruta-pdf.pdf"
my_WebView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=$url")
```

Veo que tu variable url no tiene la ruta donde esta almacenado tu archivo .pdf

```
url = URLEncoder.encode(urlPdf,"UTF-8");
mWebView.loadUrl( "http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url="  + url);
```

En lo personal la url de google drive no me ha funcionado, solo la de googleDocs.

Comment: ""my_WebView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true  //habilitar javascript
        my_WebView.settings.setSupportZoom(true)  //habilitar zoom en la vista web
        my_WebView.settings.builtInZoomControls = true //permitir pellizcar para hacer zoom
        my_WebView.settings.displayZoomControls = true //deshabilitar controles predeterminados en la pagina""  
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////Sacame de la ignorancia aqui, estas lineas simplemente son caracteristicas que se añaden al WebView eso lo pongo dentro del onCreate?

Comment: si, puede ser debajo de tu:  mWebView = findViewById(R.id.WebViewPdf);

Comment: No logro solucionarlo, podemos contactarnos?... Te pagaré si lo deseas por la ayuda

Comment: No te preocupes, escribidme y lo intentamos, si podemos lograrlo.

Comment: Ya logré solucionarlo. Gracias por el apoyo

Comment: Genial me alegra mucho, publica tu respuesta para ayudar a otros, como lo hiciste? Si lo solucionaste de otra manera, seria genial saber, actualmente tengo una implementacion pero me gustaria saber si hay otra

Comment: ya estoy preparando la solucion para subirla

Comment: cualquier duda, hazmelo saber

Answer (score 0):

La solución es esta:

1. Cambié las reglas de Storage. Solo los usuarios autenticados pueden publicar y cualqueira puede leer

`allow write: if request.auth != null;` 
`allow read: if true;`

2. Boton para el WebView. Con el boton que me permite ver el PDF me traje la URL del archivo PDF de Firestore

`MyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { @Override public void onClick(View v) { Intent i = new Intent(DetailPostActivity.this, ViewPdfActivity.class); i.putExtra("message", UrlGlobal); startActivity(i); } });`

3. Creé una variable String para almacenar "UrlGlobal"

   `urlPdf = getIntent().getStringExtra("message");`

De esa forma ya estoy trayendo la URL del PDF almacenado en firestore

4. WebView

`mWebView.loadUrl( "https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + urlPdf);`

Y con esta línea muestro el PDF almacenado en Firestone en el Web view

Comment: Genial me alegra que te funcione. Tengo una duda y es que en veces el pdf se muestra y otras no, o cuando ingresas de manera seguida no se visualiza. Te ha pasado?

Comment: si, eso pasa. No se muestra al primer intento.

Comment: Hola @roca33scorpio, puedes ayudarme a subir mi app a la playstore porfavor?

Comment: Claro dale, pero como nos contactamos, se puede por aqui al interno?

Comment: no se puede, te paso mi email: dannnymcq@gmail.com. Enviame un correo y nos contactamos

Comment: reddit, este es mi usuario Fun_Armadillo_6386 y te colaboro.

Comment: ya te envie un email

Comment: no veo el email, yo ten envie un sms en Reddit