# abrir pdf desde una carpeta de google drive

Tags: kotlin, webview, google-drive

Me encuentro tratando de abrir unos archivos desde una carpeta de google drive mediante un webview, el problema es que si bien puedo ver los archivos al momento de hacer click sobre uno de los pdf no puedo leerlos.

```
class HugoActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


private lateinit var binding: ActivityHugoBinding

private val webView: WebView? = null


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityHugoBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    title = "KotlinApp"
    val webView = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webviewhugo)
    webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
    webView.loadUrl("https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1B_HMHpvd8cpaWZziFi1y3Aqrr_41U3wp?usp=sharing")
    val webSettings = webView.settings
    webSettings.javaScriptEnabled = true
}
override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (webView!!.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack()
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
    
}
```

}[image: tocó nombre de la persona para ver su documentación alojada en google drive][image: visualizo documentación alojada en drive más no la puedo abrir al presionar sobre esta]

Comment: Presiono sobre el nombre de la persona lo cual produce que se abra el webView con el folder de google drive, luego de eso puedo visualizar todos los documentos (imagen 2) pero al presionar sobre pdf este no abre que es en el.fondo el objetivo y lo que busco.

Comment: revisa esta pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/480536/198326